# Populating Combobox with a large amount of items

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm hopeful that I can get some help/guidance from you fine folks on stackoverflow. I'm in the midst of moving everything from a vba macro project over to a C# word interop add in. For the most part, the conversion has been fine, if a little verbose as I sus out how to achieve in c# what was a 1 or 2 liner in vba. Part of my vba project has some forms, of which some have comboboxes that are loaded with data from a database server (14k+ count at this moment). This data is populated via the following code:

```
Private Sub IndividualsLoad(Optional vCompany As Variant)
'load the individuals
'if the company is provided, list the individuals in that company
  
  
  Dim sSql As String
  Dim sCompany As String
  Dim rsData As Recordset
  Dim sOldValue As String
  
  If (IsMissing(vCompany)) Then
    sSql = "SELECT DISTINCT LastName,FirstName " & _
           "FROM tblIndividuals " & _
           "ORDER BY LastName, FirstName;"
  Else
    sCompany = SQLSanatize(CStr(vCompany))
    
    sSql = "SELECT DISTINCT LastName, FirstName " & _
           "FROM tblIndividuals " & _
           "WHERE CompanyName = '" + sCompany + "' " & _
           "ORDER BY LastName, FirstName"

  End If
 
  Set rsData = New ADODB.Recordset
  rsData.Open sSql, gdb, adOpenForwardOnly
  
  sOldValue = cboIndividuals
  
  cboIndividuals.Clear
  
  Do Until rsData.EOF
    cboIndividuals.AddItem rsData("LastName") & ", " & rsData("FirstName")
    rsData.MoveNext
  Loop
  
  rsData.Close
  Set rsData = Nothing
  
  cboIndividuals = sOldValue
  
End Sub
```

that function is called on form load , and the form loads extremely quickly (Less than 2 seconds) when invoked from Word.

Doing that same thing in C# winforms has been *much* slower (as quick as about 10 seconds [Mississippily], as long as a minute and a half, whether I keep the populate individuals function in Form_Load or Form_Shown events).

I have tried various ways to speed it up combing through answers to other people's stack over flow questions. I've tried filling a data set from a dataadapter directly from the SQL server and making that the data source to the combobox:

```
        public void PopulateIndividualList()
        {
            /*start test to see if we can speed up form loading a bit*/
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Globals.ThisAddIn.GenDBConnectionString()))
            {
                string qry = GenFileNumbersLoadQry();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, conn);
                conn.Open();
                
                da.Fill(ds, "Individuals");
            }
        cboIndividuals.DataSource = ds;
        }
```

I've tried async populating of the bindinglist:

```
        public static async Task<List<Individual>> IndividualList(string sSQL)
        {
            var list = new List<Individual>();

            using (var cn = new SqlConnection { ConnectionString = Globals.ThisAddIn.GenDBConnectionString() })
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand { Connection = cn })
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = sSQL;

                    await cn.OpenAsync();

                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        list.Add(new Individual() { FirstName = reader.GetString(1), LastName = reader.GetString(0) });
                    }
                }
            }

            return list;
        }

BindingList<Individual> individuals = new BindingList<Individual>(await ServerOps.IndividualList(qry));
cboIndividuals.DataSource = individuals;
```

I've tried populating the bindinglist prior to creating the form, and just passing it in the constructor to the form and assigning the list as the data source in either the Form_Load or the Form_Shown event.

I've tried adding the items as the vba code above does in a while reader.Read() loop:

```
        private void IndividualsLoad()
        {
            string qry = GenIndividualsLoadQry();

            string connString = Globals.ThisAddIn.GenDBConnectionString();

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {

                    command.CommandText = qry;

                   connection.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            cboIndividuals.Items.Add(reader["FullName"]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I've tried adding the items via Combobox.AddRange():

```
cboIndividuals.Items.AddRange(individuals.ToArray());
```

I've tried using SendMessage from user32.dll (which acccording to one of the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230333/loading-data-in-to-a-combo-box-is-slow) would account for a 60% speed up vs. additem():

```
        private const long CB_ERR = -1;
        private const uint CB_ADDSTRING = 0x143;
        private const uint CB_RESETCONTENT = 0x14B;
        private const long CB_SETITEMDATA = 0x151;

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
            IntPtr hWnd,
            uint Msg,
            UIntPtr wParam,
            string lParam
            );

        private void AddItem(ComboBox cmb, string txt)
        {
            SendMessage(cmb.Handle, CB_ADDSTRING, UIntPtr.Zero, txt);
        }
```

I've long since lost my hair, but I'm just boggled that the vba form is *so much* quicker for the same thing.

Based on my research, it seems that populating the items into the combobox is definitely the overhead (as opposed to pulling the items down from the SQL server), which makes me assume that the myriad advanced features of the c# combobox vs the vba combobox are the cause for the difference. I toyed with just setting a custom autocomplete source:

```
            cboIndividuals.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            cboIndividuals.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            AutoCompleteStringCollection combData = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            getData(combData);
            cboIndividuals.AutoCompleteCustomSource = combData;
```

and if I do that, at least an end user can type out the person they're searching for and the form autosuggests/completes the entry, and most-importantly opens as speedily as the vba version, but I know that change is going to be super hard to swallow for my end users, and if I'm going to keep the dropdown functionality at the expense of loading speed, I'm going to have a tough sale to management of "let's use this slower version".

Does anyone have any ideas out there that I haven't tried to populate a combobox with a large amount of items, or maybe a simple vba-ish combobox without the overhead of the c# one. Or, just another idea completely, as I'm too close to this at this point. Any help/ideas/suggestions here would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: *Populating Combobox with a large amount of items* - most UI controls become unwieldy to unusable after about 20 items. Provide a search/alternative UI

Comment: *14k+ count at this moment* - beyond ridiculous for a combobox

Comment: You lost me at 14k. Even if it were performant, it is not usable by a person.

Comment: can't you just query your database after the user typed at least eg. 3 characters to avoid having 14k+ entries? with a timer, and some sort of search logic that fits to your needs. So it won't trigger the query at each keypress and will narrow your list.

Comment: Believe me, I saw everyone putting people on blast for trying to have apparently anything more than 10 items in a combobox. The thing that bothers me about these comments of "its too many items" though, is the vba version handles it -just fine-. It's clearly not too much in that technology. Philosophy aside though, the use of the combobox is for the 2% of a time a user can't find the person they're looking for because they misremembered part of their name, etc. With my custom autocomplete solution above, they lose the functionality of hunting via the dropdown.

Comment: @Tretom - Any chance you could provide an example of how to do something like that?

Comment: Is the combobox `Sorted = true`? If so, maybe switch that off and instead sort it in the database. Also, try adding the data before the combobox is created, in the form constructor. By the way, I hope your SQL doesn't embed strings in with concatenation, you really should be using parameters

Comment: Sorted is set to false. You're right I should be doing it parameterized.

Comment: Are you really planning on loading 14K+ items into a combobox, what even might often not be opened by the users ? At least don't load the items when the form loads, just the one item you need to show, and load the list when the user opens the combobox.

Comment: I just ended up giving up on the 14k combobox dream, and starting off the user with text fields visible, combobox controls hidden, and set those controls' autocomplete portion as per my code above, and if the user sets the company name to a value other than an empty string, I make the text field invisible, make the combobox visible, and populate it with the people from that company. Thank you for anyone who offered input here.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to let the users browse all the 14k items, then it's not a good solution, but what I ment is something like this. (not yet properly elaborated, but might be a good start)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ComboBox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Timer _timer;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitTimer();
        }

        private void InitTimer()
        {
            _timer = new();
            _timer.Interval = 700;
            _timer.Tick += OnTypeTimerTicked;
        }

        private void OnTypeTimerTicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Stop();

            //BeginUpdate-EndUpdate helps to gain some speed
            comboBox1.BeginUpdate();
    
            //here you can reach out to your repo and probably use AddRange instead of Add
            //here you have to filter the results according to your search logic
            //and populate the combobox
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 1");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 2");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 3");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 4");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 5");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 6");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 7");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 8");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 9");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 10");

            comboBox1.EndUpdate();
        }

        private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //your code here
            }
            finally
            {
                //maybe it's not the right place for your needs but it must be done somewhere to prevent memory leaks
                _timer.Tick -= OnTypeTimerTicked;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

one more detail about the combobox: it has an `AutocompleteMode` property. You have to set it to other than `None` - either in the Designer or in code.